# Python selenium script acts weird with Crontab on Linux

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, cron, geckodriver

Hi so I have this selenium script (using firefox and geckodriver on Raspian) that basically uses an external site to download the active stories for any given user on Instagram:

```
def download_user_stories(self, user_name):
        driver = self.driver


        driver.get("https://storiesig.com/stories/"+user_name)
        time.sleep(2)



        for i in range(1,50):
            try:
                xpath = "//div[@class='jsx-1407646540 container']//article[" + str(i) + "]//div[3]//a[1]"
                print(xpath)
                link_location = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
                link = link_location.get_attribute('href')


                current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
                corrected_time = current_time.strftime("%Y-%b-%d")

                if '.mp4' not in link: 
                    extension = '.jpg'
                else:
                    extension = '.mp4' 

                location = '/Users/"my name"/desktop/'+ user_name + '/' + corrected_time + '-' + str(i) + extension

                print (location) 

                urllib.urlretrieve(link,location)

            except Exception as e:
                print("went to except")
                print (e)
                break
```

I initially ran it through terminal and it worked fine. Then I scheduled it through crontab on raspberry pi and it ran, outputting errors to a text file and I get this:

```
working on "friends name" now
//div[@class='jsx-1407646540 container']//article[1]//div[3]//a[1]
/home/pi/Desktop/InstaScraper/Script/"friends name"/2019-Feb-21-1.jpg
//div[@class='jsx-1407646540 container']//article[2]//div[3]//a[1]
went to except
Message: Unable to locate element: //div[@class='jsx-1407646540 container']//article[2]//div[3]//a[1]
```

So it finds the first link to download but doesnt manage to find the rest even though I confirmed for this particular user there was more to download. I also confirmed **that the element it sais its unable to locate at the end is EXACTLY the XPath of the next element to download**. So I'm baffled as to why its not finding a story exactly where it should be. The stranger thing is it no longer runs fine through terminal either even though it initially did. I dont get what changed or why it didnt work in crontab like it did in terminal.

Another interesting note is it downloads all the links properly for the first user in the User_Name_List.txt but not for the rest of them. (the function is called in a loop from another function in the class that has the username list)

I've googled this and thought about it and I just cant figure out whats wrong here.

Any help and explanation would be appreciated.

**Note** - you can go on *storiesig.com* and check out the relative XPath system for various active story (not the highlights) download links yourself if you think thats maybe where the issue is.

Comment: You want to leave the jsx-1407646540 out of your xpath, those will change when he redeploys.

Comment: please show all of your code.  what is user_name?  how are you instantiating the driver?  you've left out too much

Comment: also, why are you bothering with selenium just to parse some href's out of the content?

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg I'm not familiar with beautiful soup and other methods of getting only the hrefs that you want. user_name is a string of that user's Instagram name.

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg instantiating with driver:                            
        options = Options()
        options.headless=True
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=r'/usr/bin/geckodriver')

Comment: is geckodriver executable by the cron user?

Answer (score 0):

switching from relative XPaths to absolute XPaths solved this issue.